# How to lock/unlock automatically in golang

Tags: go, struct, locking, mutex

I have a struct which has many "public" methods and I need keep threadsafe.

```
package main

import "sync"

type Test struct {
    sync.Mutex
    privateInt    int
    privateString string
    privateMap    map[string]interface{}
}

func (p *Test) A() {
    p.Lock()
    defer p.Unlock()

    // do something that changes the fields...
}

func (p *Test) B() {
    p.Lock()
    defer p.Unlock()

    // do something that changes the fields...
}

func (p *Test) C() {
    p.Lock()
    defer p.Unlock()

    // do something that changes the fields...
}

func (p *Test) D() {
    p.Lock()
    defer p.Unlock()

    // do something that changes the fields...
}

// and so on
```

If the struct has many methods,I have to check and confirm that every method do the lock.
It looks a bit stupid.

Comment: This could be a strong indication that a different design is called for. But one thing you can do is use the `atomic` package, at least for fields that are based on fundamental types.

Comment: Also note that you don't need any synchronization if you're _only_ reading the values. You'd only need to lock for writes... and your example code doesn't show any writes, so based purely on your example, you could just remove the locks entirely, and still be thread safe.

Answer (score 0):

I think of a way like database.
I wrap the struct Test with another struct TestProvider, and I must call Transaction() to get the pointer before use the Test.

```
package main

import "sync"

type Test struct {
    privateInt    int
    privateString string
    privateMap    map[string]interface{}
}

func (p *Test) A() {
    // do something that changes the fields...
}

func (p *Test) B() {
    // do something that changes the fields...
}

func (p *Test) C() {
    // do something that changes the fields...
}

func (p *Test) D() {
    // do something that changes the fields...
}

// and so on

type TestProvider struct {
    sync.Mutex
    test *Test
}

func (p *TestProvider) Transaction(callback func(test *Test)) {
    p.Lock()
    defer p.Unlock()
    callback(p.test)
}

func NewTestProvider(test *Test) *TestProvider {
    return &TestProvider{
        test: test,
    }
}

func main() {
    p := NewTestProvider(&Test{})
    go p.Transaction(func(test *Test) {
        test.A()
        test.B()
    })
    go p.Transaction(func(test *Test) {
        test.C()
        test.D()
    })
}
```

It works well,but I think that there may be a better way.